# openapi-generator-maven-plugin specify jackson property naming strategy

Tags: java, swagger, openapi, swagger-codegen, openapi-generator-maven-plugin

As of now, we are getting the models generated from the open api spec file with snake case as below (only the json property)

```
  @JsonProperty("email_id")
  private String emailId;
```

Would like to see if there is a possibility to make the JsonProperty camel case like below.

```
  @JsonProperty("emailId")
  private String emailId;
```

Currently am using

```
<groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
<artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>5.2.0</version>
```

Comment: Could you please send your inputSpec file?
Maybe the problem is because of the model attributes are in snake case on this file.